# Capturing Specific Parts of InputStreamReader in Java

Tags: java, loops, command-line-arguments, ping, interrupt

So I'm working on a minor GUI that pings from the command line an IP that is selected from the IP list.  I have this working and returning to an output via the getInputStream.

Here's the code I have for running the ping:

```
    String pingResult = "";
    try {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec("ping " + IPAddressList.getSelectedValue());
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                (p.getInputStream()))) {
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                pingResult += inputLine;
            }
        }

    }//try
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

What I need to do now, is from a list of IPs (which is stored inside of a Jlist with a DefaultModel names machines), I need to continuously allow the IPs of the list to be pinged and the list to be updated (I've got an idea on how to do the updating).

I have no idea how to kick off this loop using some of the code above and keep it running.  Also, while it is running, I need to make sure that the GUI can do other things, such as: remove an IP from the list, add an IP to the list, ping an individual IP, etc.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to kick off the pinging within a background thread.  Using a `SwingWorker` may be the easiest way to implement this.  You can fairly easily pass it a list of IP addresses and it will run in the background pinging each one and then pass the intermediate results back to your GUI.  One of the nice things about the `SwingWorker` class is that it ensures that processing of the results occurs within the main event dispatch thread for Swing so that you do not need to do anything extra to handle this.

The Javadoc provides a good overview of the usage for it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Below is a rough starting point.  You'll then instantiate it and call its `execute()` method to start the background process.

```
class PingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, PingResult> {
    private List<IpAddress> addresses;

    public PingWorker(List<IpAddress> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        for (IpAddress address : addresses) {
            // run ping code and build result
            publish(new PingResult(address /* other result params here */));
        }

        // no need to return anything as we are processing the intermediate results
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        // pings are complete, update GUI to reflect this
    }

     @Override
     protected void process(List<PingResult> results) {
         for (PingResult result : results) {
             // update GUI with the result of the ping such as your table model
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: This looks awesome Ed, I will try and get the coding done tomorrow.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You could launch everything in your try loop on a different thread so that it runs independently, then you can do whatever you wish (add/remove IP's) while it continues to run.

Follow through this tutorial, and you will find most of what you need:
[Java Tutorials: Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)